# Issue in saving figure in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python. I am trying to save the figure but I am unable to do so properly. My code is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataFilePath = 'file.txt';
data=pd.read_csv(dataFilePath, delim_whitespace=True, skipinitialspace=True);


I = data['I'];
A = data['A'];
B = data['B'];
C = data['C'];
D = data['D'];
E = data['E'];
F = data['F'];
xAxis = list(range(1,len(I)+1));
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(xAxis, np.log10(A), 'r-s', label='A')
plt.plot(xAxis, np.log10(D), 'r-^', label='D')
plt.plot(xAxis, np.log10(B), 'g-s', label='B')
plt.plot(xAxis, np.log10(E), 'g-^', label='E')
plt.plot(xAxis, np.log10(C), 'b-s', label='C')
plt.plot(xAxis, np.log10(F), 'b-^', label='F')

plt.xlabel('X Axis');
plt.ylabel('Y Axis');

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, ncol=3, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)

plt.savefig('myimage.png', format='png', dpi=1200)
```

I am not getting the desired result as I want. The legends are not proper in auto saved figure. Snapshots are attached in the image for both cases (desired and getting):

[image: Actual and desired result]

Comment: try using `plt.tight_layout()`

Comment: in my case, defining the figsize such as plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) helped.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my application setting the size of the figure using a command such as:
  plt.figure(1).set_size_inches(10,12), to adjust the aspect ratio helped.

Comment: Thank you Abrie Nel